# COUNTIFS with array criteria and array exceptions

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif

I need to COUNT 5 versions of (Begin with...) text in cell,

with 3 versions of (End with...) exception.

For this goal i write next formula:

```
=IF(SUM(COUNTIFS(A2,{"Begin1","Begin2","Begin3","Begin4","Begin5"}&".*Text*",A2,"<>"&{"*End1","*End2","*End3"}))=0,"NO","OK")
```

Unfortunately its working only with 3 texts and 3 exceptions.

How to make this formula working with 5 texts and 3 exceptions?

Comment: How many other distinct values of "Begin#" do you have?

Comment: So why not use “Be*" which gets any Begin but not any End.

Comment: @Skin I have 13 Begins total, and 3 End exception total.

Comment: Well you have "Begin1","Begin2","Begin3" and I suggested "Be*" so did you replace your 3 versions with my version? That is why I wrote it like that.

Comment: @Solar Mike Yes, you right, but this is only an exemple. In real file is not similar words,

Comment: Then I have shown you the method, it is up to you to match it to your data if the example is so poor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'r probably looking for something like:

```
=IF((SUM(COUNTIF(A2,{"Begin1","Begin2","Begin3","Begin4","Begin5"}&"*"))=1)*(SUM(COUNTIF(A1,"*"&{"End1","End2","End3"}))=0),"OK","NO")
```